# What's the difference between Keras' AUC(curve='PR') and Scikit-learn's average_precision_score?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, auc, precision-recall

I am quite confused on the difference between Keras' `AUC(curve='PR')` and Scikit-learn's `average_precision_score`. My objective is to compute the Area Under the Precision-Recall Curve (AUPRC), for both Scikit-learn and Keras models. However, these two metrics yield vastly different results!

Did I miss something out on the TensorFlow-Keras documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC, with regards to the use of the `AUC` function?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157012/area-under-precision-recall-curve-auc-of-pr-curve-and-average-precision-ap

Comment: @PV8 Thanks for the link, it helped in the understanding of the differences! Tldr, scikit-learn's implementation isn't interpolated if I understood it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the Scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#precision-recall-and-f-measures),  they use a different implementation method:

> References [Manning2008] and [Everingham2010] present alternative variants of AP that interpolate the precision-recall curve. Currently, average_precision_score does not implement any interpolated variant. References [Davis2006] and [Flach2015] describe why a linear interpolation of points on the precision-recall curve provides an overly-optimistic measure of classifier performance. This linear interpolation is used when computing area under the curve with the trapezoidal rule in auc.

In the `average_precision_score` function [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score), you can also read:

> This implementation is not interpolated and is different
> from computing the area under the precision-recall curve with the
> trapezoidal rule, which uses linear interpolation and can be too
> optimistic.

I encourage you to look in detail at the different functions and their descriptions available in the [metrics module](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py). I also highly recommend to read the [related paper](https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/%7Epage/rocpr.pdf).

Lastly, there's also a potentially interested thread here: [[AUC] result of tf.metrics.auc doesnot match with sklearn's](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14834).

Comment: Thank you for the links to the relevant documentations, appreciate it. I've gone through them and its much clearer now! If I understood them correctly, the main reason for the discrepancy is that Scikit-learn's `average_precision_score` is not interpolated.

Comment: One of the main yes; a good exercise would consist in comparing side by side tf and scikit-learn algorithms to understand the key differences :)